# Attribute not being parsed retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a class I am attempting to parse with retrofit:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class StickerDto(
        @Json (name = "totalAnimatedStickers") val total: Int,
        @Json(name = "pages") val pages: Int,
        @Json(name = "data") val stickers: List<Sticker>

)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class Sticker(
        @Json(name = "name") val name: String,
        @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
        @Json(name = "stickerData") val stickerData: Map<String, Any>,
        var isSelected:Boolean = false
)
```

Below is the beginning of the response that I receive with a 200. Note that the "stickerData" attribute of the sticker class is a very long JSON string that I am attempting to get as a Map. I cannot include the whole thing because it is very long. Attempting to get it as a string fails because Retrofit is expecting a JSON object.

```
{"totalAnimatedStickers":48,"pages":6,"data":[{"name":"zany_face","id":"9b50585a-1fa5-4b02-9a50-d1310ccc7d0a","stickerData":{"v":"5.5.7","fr":24,"ip":0,"op":48,"w":1024,"h":1024,"nm":"zany_face","ddd":0,"assets":[{"id":"comp_0","layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":3,"nm":"C | Face_CTRL","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[512,849.778,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":0,"s":[100,100,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833,1]},"o":{"x":[0.292,0.292,0.193],"y":[0.025,0.034,0]},"t":4,"s":[105,94,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.667,0.667,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.167,0.167,0.167],"y":[0.167,0.167,0]},"t":8,"s":[97.304,102.544,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.667,0.667,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":12,"s":[100,100,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":18,"s":[100,100,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833,1]},"o":{"x":[0.292,0.292,0.193],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":21,"s":[105,94,100]},{"i":{"x":[0,0,0.704],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.167,0.167,0.167],"y":[0.167,0.167,0]},"t":24,"s":[96.304,104.544,100]},{"t":32,"s":[100,100,100]}],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"ef":[{"ty":5,"nm":"Controller","np":13,"mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller","ix":1,"en":1,"ef":[{"ty":6,"nm":"Icon","mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller-0001","ix":1,"v":0},{"...........
```

Here is the method I use to create the retrofit instance:

private fun createNewFriendsClient(authRefreshClient: AuthRefreshClient,
preferencesInteractor: PreferencesInteractor): FriendsApiClient {

```
val logger = run {
    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
    }
}


val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logger).authenticator(RefreshUserAuthenticator(authRefreshClient, preferencesInteractor,
        UnauthorizedNavigator(SDKInternal.appContext, Interactors.preferences))).build()

return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttp)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(Interactors.apiEndpoint)
        .build()
        .create(FriendsApiClient::class.java)
```

}

My problem is, the "stickers" attribute of the StickerDto class is null after making the call, meaning something is wrong with the way I am parsing this data with Retrofit. What am I missing?

Comment: the annotations you are using are from Moshi but your convert factory is Gson

Comment: Use `@SerializedName` instead of `@Json`

Comment: Thanks so much, friends. This was it.